# Run time Error '91' Object Variable or with block variable not set : Macro Working on Windows but not working on Mac OS

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Please help me debug my code, Having problems migrating the code from Windows OS to Mac OS

```
Sub ImportRooms()
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
   Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
   Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim Fnd As Range
   
   Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
   
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.csv"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Show
      If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
         Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
         Set Fnd = Range("A:A").Find("report output", , , xlPart, , , False, , False)
        Sheet2.Range("A1:AN112").ClearContents
    
        With Sheets(1)
            .Range(Range("A1"), Fnd.Offset(1)).Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
            .Range(Fnd.Offset(1), Range("AO500")).Copy Sheet2.Range("A20")
        End With
   
    wkbSourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
  End If
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: `Filedialog` doesn't work on a Mac. You have to use MacScript.

Comment: You might find inspiration [here](https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/).

Comment: Read [this](https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/) about sandboxing of Excel on a Mac, you can not use files from the Desktop for example.